# What does she exactly say?

Tags: conversation, listening

> Man: Oh, God! Did you....um...Did you set the alarm before we left? 
>       Woman: Yes, the last thing I did!
>       Man: No, I was the last one to leave. I was the last one to leave and I'm sure I didn't set it.
>       Woman: No darling, I was the last one out and I did, I promise.
>       Man: Are you sure?
>       Woman: Yep!
>       Man: Okay.....No, no, I was the last one 'cause I went back in.
>               And that means the alarm is not set. Cause I didn't set it.
>     Woman: Well, I guess ___________________________________.
>       Man: Well, just like your old college days.

Video clip link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yReEv4N3l50

**Please fill the blank. I need her exact line.**

There were already English subtitles for it, but I found they are not properly written.

*Ps. Please forgive me if this type of question is not allowed at this site.
I never post again, I promise.*

Comment: Is this line the only one that you need to be precise?

Comment: @Stephie Thanks for giving the exact line. Actually, there are a lot. It's a pity that my listening skill is too bad to catch all of the lines precisely. Can you please help more by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I was able to extract from the clip.

> 0:10
>   (There are two voices going on at the same time. One is possibly *"Hi, Teddy"*, though it could as well be *"Hi, today"*, then there is a man and a woman talking to each other in the background (barely audible) throughout the clip up until the part where the two main characters start the dialogue. The other voice is supposed to be the translation of the standard announcement of Thai Airways during the safety demonstration. In the movie, it seems like they speak each line in English first, then the same line in Thai, which is the opposite of what I'm more used to: Thai then English. So, this line should be the translation of the next line in Thai: *"Prior to take off and landing, window shades must be pulled up."*)
>
> 0:14
>   ก่อนเครื่องบินขึ้นและลง กรุณาเปิดหน้าต่างด้วยค่ะ
>   (See the translation above.)
>
> 0:18
>   *Please keep your seat belt fastened low and tight when seated at all times.*
>   (This is barely audible, particularly the word "Please", but the *keep*, *your seat belt fastened low*, and *at all times* parts are clear enough.)
>
> 0:24
>   เมื่อนั่งประจำที่ กรุณารัดเข็มขัดให้กระชับตลอดเวลา
>   (See the translation above.)
>
> 0:32
>   *Tsk. Not again. Did you, um, did you set the alarm before we left?*
>   *Yeah, it was the last thing I did.*
>   *No, I was the last one to leave. I was the last one to leave and I'm sure I didn't set it.*
>   *No, darling. I was the last one out. And I did. I promise.*
>   *You sure?*
>   *Yep.*
>   *Okay.* (pause for a brief moment) *No, no, I-I was the last one, 'cause I went back in. And that means the alarm is not set 'cause I didn't set it.*
>   ***Well, I guess that means we'll be coming home to a large bunch of hippies sleeping in our bed.***
>   *What? Just like your old college days?* (chuckles)
>   (chuckles)

Comment: Thank you for all correcting! I am glad that I got to know there had been a few mistakes. Your script was a great help.

Comment: Allow me to ask this please : Which one do you think the man's last line 'just like your old college days' indicates, ***'She used to be one of hippies in her old cellege days'*** or ***'She has ever experienced coming across a lot of hippies in her house in her old college days'***?

Comment: @Bunch I think anything is possible. I don't usually try to read into the dialogue too much. However, I guess that their case is not very different from mine. Back in my days, I frequently had a large group of friends (and friends of friends!) staying overnight at my place, which was a small bachelor apartment room, a perfect place for crashing after a long night. ;-)

Comment: Hahah XD Thanks a lot! By the way, I wonder if you could possibly help me complete a script for a movie titled 'Alive' 1993 film. There was already a subtitle, but it's awfully shortened here and there. I can send you a copy of the movie and the uncompleted lines I did so far. I know I am asking too much and it will be time-consuming work, nonetheless I hope you would do me a favor please?

Comment: I'm sorry @Bunch.I'm afraid I can't do that. A full-length movie is really long. Also, asking for the transcription of a clip could be frowned upon by some members already. (On one hand, it's very localized. On the other hand, it's very useful for learners. So, it's unclear whether it's off or on-topic.) Still, I'd recommend you to try your best first and then post the parts you really have trouble with as a question on ELL like you just did. Happy ELLing!

Comment: Okay. I'll try my best :) Thanks again for the transcription.

Answer (score 2):

It's

> Well, I guess, that means we'll be coming home to a large bunch of hippies, sleeping in our bed.

Answer (score 1):

that's fine. Post it for all sake. I have seen many such questions asking about 'what someone says'. After all, you have 'tagged' this question well!

Anyway,

I hear this.

> *Well, I guess, that means we will be coming home large bunch of hippies sleeping in our bed.*

But let the native speakers here *confirm* it! :)